# Java - How can I put input strings within a 2d array of random letters?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Alright, so I am making a word search for my Java course where the program gets user input for the amount of columns and rows, then input for each word. I have a 2d array that outputs a grid of random letters and I am having trouble putting the input letters within the grid. Below is the code I am working with:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Unnecessary welcome message I thought would be nice to add in
        System.out.printf("Welcome to my word search generator! Let me guide you through the process.%n%n");

        // 2d array with specified rows and columns
        int[] specRows = new int[getRows()]; // Array for rows
        int[] specColumns = new int[getColumns()]; // Array for columns

        String[] words = new String[getColumns()];
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        for (int i = 0; i < specColumns.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter a word with less than %d characters: ", specColumns.length);
            words[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < specColumns.length; i++) { // Outputs a line of letters per column
            System.out.println(words[i].replace("", "  ").trim());
            for (int j = 0; j < specRows.length; j++) // Loop to specify length of a line
                System.out.printf(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length()))+"  ");
        }
    }

    public static int getRows() { // method for rows
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("First, enter the number of rows: ");
        if (keyboard.hasNextInt()) { // Check if input is an integer
            int rows = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (rows >= 2 && rows <= 15) // Double check to see if input is reasonable
                return rows;
            else { //Integer check
                System.out.printf("Oh yeah, we can only have 2-15 rows in this puzzle.%n");
                return getRows(); // Go back to the top and reprompt for input
            }
        } else { // Validation check
            System.out.printf("Input has to be an integer.%n");
            return getRows();
        }
    }

    public static int getColumns() { // method for columns
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Alright, now enter the number of columns: ");
        if (keyboard.hasNextInt()) { // Check if input is an integer
            int columns = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (columns >= 2 && columns <= 15) // Double check to see if input is reasonable
                return columns;
            else {  //Integer check
                System.out.printf("Just so we're clear, the puzzle needs 2-15 columns to be reasonable.%n");
                return getColumns(); // Go back to the top and reprompt for input
            }
        } else { // Validation check
            System.out.printf("Input has to be an integer.%n");
            return getColumns();
        }
    }
}
```

In advance, I am aware that calling my column method a bunch of times will produce glitchy results, but I could not figure out a better way to implement the code, and this is exactly why I am here.

Comment: Try using `String[] words = new String[specColumns.length];` instead. ;)

Comment: Alright, that clears up my annoying method glitch, but my main end goal of this problem is to place input words in a grid of randomized letters. I can output a list of input letters and I can make a grid of randomized letters, but what puzzles me is how to merge the two together.